# Template and typedef errors

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I've got this class:

```
template <class T>
class NodoLista
{
public:
    T dato;
    Puntero<NodoLista<T>> sig;
    NodoLista<T>(const T& e, Puntero<NodoLista<T>> s) : dato(e), sig(s)  { };
};
```

then i try using the typedef like this:

```
template <class U>
typedef Puntero<NodoLista<U>> pNodoLista;
void main()
{
    pNodoLista<int> nodo = new NodoLista<int>(1, nullptr);
    cout<<nodo->dato<<endl;
}
```

and I get an error saying that my template is incorrect.
How can I use the typedef to use:

```
Puntero<NodoLista<T>> as pNodoLista<T>
```

Comment: I tried what is in that topic and it didnt worked. Thats why i opened a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use

```
template <class T>
using pNodoLista = Puntero<NodoLista<T>>;
```

Now `pNodoLista<T>` is equivalent to `Puntero<NodoLista<T>>`.

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/SU9wzq)

If your compiler doesn't support c++11, you can use a workaround:

```
template <class T>
struct pNodoLista
{
    typedef Puntero<NodoLista<T>> type;
};
```

Now `pNodoLista<T>::type` is equivalent to `Puntero<NodoLista<T>>`.

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/slu5Zq)

BTW: `main()` should return `int`.

Comment: I get an syntax error 'using' and The template declaration does not parse correctly

Comment: @FaustoSanchez What compiler are you using? I've added a live demo. http://ideone.com/SU9wzq

Comment: I dont know how to tell you what compilar am i using. How can i do that?

Comment: @FaustoSanchez gcc, clang, or visual studio? Anyway, your compiler need to support c++11 for this solution.

Comment: Im using visual studio, how can i now if my compiler supports c++11? Does visual studio supports it?

Comment: @FaustoSanchez Alias templates is supported from VS2013. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

Comment: ive got vs 2012, is there a solution for my problem with this version of visual studio? Thank you man!

Comment: @FaustoSanchez If you can't upgrade your compiler, I added a workaround in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class U>
typedef Puntero<NodoLista<U>> pNodoLista;
```

should be

```
typedef template <class U> Puntero<NodoLista<U>> pNodoLista;
```

Comment: Which error in particular? Improve your question please!

Comment: I get this errors: "syntax error 'template<', not declarated identifier U